# How to configure Emacs to work like the Visual Studio Code Remote Containers extension

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, emacs

I'm new to Emacs and I'm trying to configure it as my IDE for development of a python project inside a container. The source code lives in the host pc and is mounted as a volume in the docker container which has all the necessary dependencies and libraries for the project.

This is a normal setup for ROS2 projects and works well with [this vscode extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers). I've installed doom emacs and opened the file and project using TRAMP, but lsp-mode won't start.

I found [this page](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/remote/) but I haven't managed to configure it properly. In my latest attempt I added the following to my config.el:

```lisp
(after! lsp (lsp-register-client
 (make-lsp-client
  :new-connection (lsp-tramp-connection (lambda () lsp-python-ms-executable)
                                        (lambda () (f-exists? lsp-python-ms-executable)))
  :major-modes (append '(python-mode) lsp-python-ms-extra-major-modes)
  :remote? t
  :server-id 'pyls-remote
  :priority 1
  :initialization-options 'lsp-python-ms--extra-init-params
  :notification-handlers (lsp-ht ("python/languageServerStarted" 'lsp-python-ms--language-server-started-callback)
                                 ("telemetry/event" 'ignore)
                                 ("python/reportProgress" 'lsp-python-ms--report-progress-callback)
                                 ("python/beginProgress" 'lsp-python-ms--begin-progress-callback)
                                 ("python/endProgress" 'lsp-python-ms--end-progress-callback))
  :initialized-fn (lambda (workspace)
                    (with-lsp-workspace workspace
                      (lsp--set-configuration (lsp-configuration-section "python"))))
  :download-server-fn (lambda (client callback error-callback update?)
                        (when lsp-python-ms-auto-install-server
                          (lsp-python-ms--install-server client callback error-callback update?))))))
```

but I keep getting this error:

> LSP :: There are no language servers supporting current mode `python-mode` registered with `lsp-mode`.
> This issue might be caused by:
>
> 1. The language you are trying to use does not have built-in support in `lsp-mode`. You must install the required support manually. Examples of this are `lsp-java` or `lsp-metals`.
> 2. The language server that you expect to run is not configured to run for major mode `python-mode`. You may check that by checking the `:major-modes` that are passed to `lsp-register-client`.
> 3. `lsp-mode` doesn't have any integration for the language behind `python-mode`. Refer to https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/languages and https://langserver.org/ .
> 4. You are over `tramp`. In this case follow https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/remote/.
> 5. You have disabled the `lsp-mode` clients for that file. (Check `lsp-enabled-clients` and `lsp-disabled-clients`).

pyls is already installed in the docker container. Can you please help me configure emacs properly for this scenario?

Comment: The subject line is not descriptive of the problem/question.  Could you please edit that to be relevant to the issue? (Which appears to be about the combination of tramp + lsp-mode + python).  You shouldn't expect Emacs users to know what VS Code does in general, but it also doesn't seem relevant. (From what little I know of VS Code, I believe Tramp *doesn't* work the same way -- even if the end results are similar -- so it's a confusing way to have phrased it.)